# Spring MVC tomcat constant 404 error when trying to display .jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

im trying to get my web app to display anything other that 404 error, but can't figure out what is wrong with the code. Here it is:

HomeController:

```
package pl.borys.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return"test";

    }
}
```

AppConfig:

```
package pl.borys.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pl.borys")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

AppInitializer:

```
package pl.borys.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

the file structure is as follows:

```
src
]--main
 ]--java
 | ]--pl.borys
 |  ]--config
 |   ]--AppConfig
 |   ]--AppInitializer
 |  ]--controller
 |   ]--HelloController
 ]--webapp
 | ]--WEB-INF
 |  ]--views
 |   ]--test.jsp
```

And whatever address I type it displays 404 error. Im trying to access the test.jsp under following address:

> http://localhost:8080/home

edit: 
Here is my pom.xml with dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.borys</groupId>
    <artifactId>springkurwamac</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ServletContextInitializer` instead of `WebApplicationInitializer` put `@Configuration` annotation on it and change `servlet.addMapping("/")` to `servlet.addMapping("/*")`.

Comment: Thanks for response. What should I import to be able to use this class? I did some google research and it looks like it is used for Spring Boot, but im not using it here.

Comment: Ahh, sorry my bad, anyway, at first let's try with changing `/` to `/*`

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt fix the problem. Is there a possibility that the prefix in viewResolver is wrong? Could it be that it starts from a wrong dir? I tried adding `../` in front of it but it didnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Now let's try this: `viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);`

Comment: If I understand correctly Im supposed to replace `viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");` with `viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);` right?

Comment: No, don't replace anything, just add this to yours `viewResolver` bean.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I made a new project, downloaded tomcat again and the issue solved itself somehow.